# Can I redirect puppet agent output to a different log file?

Tags: logging, puppet, redhat

I have a RHEL 6.10 node on which I installed the Puppet agent (version 5.3.5). The output of the Puppet run is currently logged in /var/log/messages. However I want to redirect this logging to a different file (ex. /var/log/puppet/puppet.log) to make things more clear. I already looked in /etc/sysconfig/puppet but the only things listed in there is this:

```
# You may specify parameters to the puppet client here
#PUPPET_EXTRA_OPTS=--waitforcert=500
```

I already tried adding this to the config:

```
# Where to log to. Specify syslog to send log messages to the system log.
PUPPET_LOG=/var/log/puppet/puppet.log
```

And then restarted the Puppet service but this doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone tell me how to do this and if this is even possible on RH 6.10?

Answer (score 2):

`puppet agent` has a command-line option `--logdest` which you can set to a filename. By default `puppet agent` logs to `syslog`, which is why you are seeing messages in `/var/log/messages`.

If you are running a recent version of `puppet agent` (around 5.5 or so) you can also add `logdest` to the `[agent]` section of `puppet.conf`.